# PHPmailer double from inside header

Tags: php, mailer

When I send a email by a PHP script the receivers sees two "from" addresses, like this

```
 Subject:   About this
 From:      me@example.com
 From:      me@web01.example.com
 Receiver:  you@example.com
```

How can I change or get the second from with the webserver out of there?

This problem occurs since the update of Apache and MySQL...

Before there wasn't a second from:

Any suggestions?

Here a little piece of PHP code what has been used.

```
  // Class start    
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

  // From
    $mail->From = $config['email'];
    $mail->FromName = $config['name'];

  // To         
    if(!is_array($email)){
        $mail->ClearAddresses();
        $mail->AddAddress($email);
        $mail->Send();
    } else{
        foreach($email as $email){
            $mail->ClearAddresses();
            $mail->AddAddress($email);
            $mail->Send();
```

If I take a look at email from before the update the Return Path + Sender (inside Header) are the same as the email adres. Like it should be.

But after the update the Return Path + Sender say me@web01.example.com so that looks like the problem?

*I am now using SMTP and sendmail was giving these problems since the update. SMTP solved it.*

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.**

Comment: post your php code, for more and better responses

Comment: done, added some code

Comment: @user2838753: is the second from address you are getting of your webserver?

Comment: Yes, correct. But it has been solved. I am now using SMTP and sendmail was giving these problems since the update. SMTP solved it.

Comment: @user2838753: ok,nice. Please post the updates as answer so that it might help someone facing the same issue you faced few hrs ago.